# Trouble dual booting Ubuntu 14.04.3 with Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

Tried to dual boot Ubuntu 14.04.3 on a Windows 10 laptop and I am getting an error.

I am using a Pendrive USB and have turned off Secure Boot, set partitions and turned off Fast startup.

The laptop is a HP Pavilion 64 bit

[[image: picture 1]] 
The laptop information is here if that is of any help

[[image: picture 2]]

Comment: Try `rufus` instead of PendriveUSB and check md5 .iso and check disk for defects before run option `install`

Comment: I lent my USB to my friend and he was able to successfully dual boot Ubuntu with windows 10, so im sure the USB is not a problem

Answer (score 0):

HP Pavillion computers, assuming you have an older model, do not have motherboards compatible with USB 3.0. Try using an older USB drive that is 2.0.
The issue could also be the drive is not formatted as FAT32, but that's very unlikely since you're using PenDriveLinux.